# How to get json data when url give .txt

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a preblem about get json data form url

example url:

> https://books.google.com/books?bibkeys=ISBN:1118691784,OCLC:879947237,LCCN:&jscmd=viewapi&callback=updateGBSCover

this url is give .txt and .txt have json data

I have no idea to get json data in .txt for show in page

Thanks for help me :)

Comment: Are you looking for `JSON.parse()` ? [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: The response is not JSON.  It appears to be actual javascript.  You could use eval but that would be a really bad idea from a security standpoint.

Comment: @Ploppy I try `this.http.get("https://xxxx").subscribe(data => {
        this.itemss=JSON.parse(data['_body']);
        console.log(this.itemss);
      });` it's work I get json data but it's error `EXCEPTION: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

Comment: The file is probably not only JSON. Maybe the JSON start after a few chars.

Answer (score 0):

The data is in JSONP format, e.g. JSON wrapped in a callback

More information here: https://developers.google.com/books/

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://books.google.com/books?bibkeys=ISBN:1118691784,OCLC:879947237,LCCN:&jscmd=viewapi",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: "updateGBSCover"
});

function updateGBSCover(data) {
  // console.log(data);
  $("#result").append($('<img/>',{"src": data["OCLC:879947237"].thumbnail_url}));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: thanks! but I'm sorry my app use typescript